# Java - Selenium - Boolean method always returns false

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver, boolean

```
public boolean checkRemoveButtonAvailability() {
    List<WebElement> buttonsOnPage = findAll(BUTTONS);
    for (WebElement button : buttonsOnPage) {
        String buttonText = button.getText();
        if (buttonText.equals("Remove")) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Test
public void removeButtonHasBeenCleared() {
.......
assertFalse(userSearchPage.checkRemoveButtonAvailability());
    }
```

I use the above method `checkRemoveButtonAvailability()` in my test, and the result of the test is always passed, although during the tests I check if **Remove** Button is available or not.

Also if I delete the last return type `return true`, the IDE tells me that a return type must be added.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is incorrect:

```
else {
    return false;
}
```

If your first button which is checked does not contain the desired text, the method returns false, and the loop is finished.

Delete this `else` statement and you are fine.

The final `return` must be `false`.

Comment: It's not enough to delete the 'else' statement, also should change the return value to false after the for loop. Otherwise this method will always return true.

Comment: +1. this is indeed right. I thought it was already false, which it should be by default.

Comment: I deleted the else statement and made the last return value to false. and also the other way around (first false then true). And test is passed no matter if button is available or not.

Comment: @edward.eas Print out the 'buttonText' attribute for every button in the loop, maybe it's always empty or the are some special characters in it.

Comment: And, maybe you should use your debugger to check what values you receive.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was solved after changing getText with getAttribute. and also with removing else block.